# How to get rows with COUNT = 0 in an Oracle SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a Oracle SQL table which stores Document Informations. The table has 3 columns (ID, creationDate, status).  There are only 2 status ("STATUS1", "STATUS2")

For each available date and status, I want to have the total number of documents with those characteristics (including when total count = 0).

My code is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(D.CREATED_ON, 'DD-MM-YY') AS DATE, D.STATUS, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM DOCUMENTS D
GROUP BY DISTINCT TO_CHAR(D.CREATED_ON, 'DD-MM-YY'), D.STATUS
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Which returns:

```
| DATE      | STATUS | TOTAL |
|-----------|--------|-------|
| 14-01-22  | STATUS1| 2     |
| 14-01-22  | STATUS2| 1     |
| 15-01-22  | STATUS2| 3     |
| 16-01-22  | STATUS1| 2     |
```

I want it to return:

```
| DATE     | STATUS | TOTAL |
|----------|--------|-------|
| 14-01-22 |STATUS1 | 2     |
| 14-01-22 |STATUS2 | 1     |
| 15-01-22 |STATUS1 | 0     | <--
| 15-01-22 |STATUS2 | 3     |
| 16-01-22 |STATUS1 | 2     |
| 16-01-22 |STATUS2 | 0     | <--
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't select what's not there, so you'll need something like a calander table which has all the dates

Comment: The problem are not the dates. I only want to count the dates that are registered in the table (skip the dates that are not in the table).  
If there is a document created on 12-10-22 with STATUS1 and for that date there is no document with STATUS2 , I want to obtain a row that count it as 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill in date gaps for all groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947659/fill-in-date-gaps-for-all-groups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some *help* - as HoneyBadger commented, a kind of *calendar*.  Two of them, actually, to name all statuses and all dates involved.

With sample data

```
SQL> with documents (id, created_on, status) as
  2    (select 1, date '2022-01-14', 'STATUS1' from dual union all
  3     select 2, date '2022-01-14', 'STATUS1' from dual union all
  4     select 3, date '2022-01-14', 'STATUS2' from dual union all
  5     select 4, date '2022-01-15', 'STATUS2' from dual union all
  6     select 5, date '2022-01-15', 'STATUS2' from dual union all
  7     select 6, date '2022-01-15', 'STATUS2' from dual union all
  8     select 7, date '2022-01-16', 'STATUS1' from dual union all
  9     select 8, date '2022-01-16', 'STATUS1' from dual
 10    ),
```

and *the help*,

```
 11  all_statuses as
 12    (select distinct status
 13     from documents
 14    ),
 15  all_dates as
 16    (select distinct created_on
 17     from documents
 18    )
 19  select s.created_on, a.status, count(d.id) total
 20  from all_statuses a cross join all_dates s
 21       left join documents d on d.status = a.status and d.created_on = s.created_on
 22  group by s.created_on, a.status
 23  order by s.created_on, a.status;
```

the result is

```
CREATED_ON STATUS       TOTAL
---------- ------- ----------
14-01-2022 STATUS1          2
14-01-2022 STATUS2          1
15-01-2022 STATUS1          0
15-01-2022 STATUS2          3
16-01-2022 STATUS1          2
16-01-2022 STATUS2          0

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of distinct statuses, but do not know dates, you may use [partitioned outer join](https://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/270646.htm), which will generate all additional statuses for you:

> ```
> create table t
> as
> select
>   date '2022-01-01'
>   + trunc(level/3) as dt
>   , case
>       when dbms_random.value() > 0.5
>       then 'STATUS1'
>       else 'STATUS2'
>   end as status
> from dual
> connect by level < 15
> ```

> ```
> with s(status) as (
>   /*All possible statuses*/
>   select 'STATUS1' from dual
>   union all
>   select 'STATUS2' from dual
> )
> , agg as (
>   select
>     dt, status
>     , count(1) as cnt
>   from t
>   group by
>     dt, status
> )
> select
>   dt, status
>   , nvl(cnt, 0) as cnt
> from agg
>   partition by (dt)
>   right join s
>     using (status)
> ```
>
> ```
> DT        | STATUS  | CNT
> :-------- | :------ | --:
> 01-JAN-22 | STATUS1 |   1
> 01-JAN-22 | STATUS2 |   1
> 02-JAN-22 | STATUS1 |   2
> 02-JAN-22 | STATUS2 |   1
> 03-JAN-22 | STATUS1 |   3
> 03-JAN-22 | STATUS2 |   0
> 04-JAN-22 | STATUS1 |   1
> 04-JAN-22 | STATUS2 |   2
> 05-JAN-22 | STATUS1 |   2
> 05-JAN-22 | STATUS2 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=39dcf42b8f1762e973557c54712ecd97)*